# How to Advance Compress Partition And Sub Partition in Oracle Table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, partitioning

How to Advance Compress Partition And Sub Partition In an oracle table .
The table is already having data , I need to compress Old data as well as the new data which will come .
Partition name were system generated name .
Database is Oracle11g

Table Structure :

```
CREATE TABLE SCH.STU_DATA
(
  ROLL_NO          NUMBER,
  P_DATE    DATE
  S_VALUE  VARCHAR2(10 CHAR)
)
NOCOMPRESS 
TABLESPACE DATA_PARTS
RESULT_CACHE (MODE DEFAULT)
PCTUSED    0
PCTFREE    10
INITRANS   1
MAXTRANS   255
STORAGE    (
            BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
            FLASH_CACHE      DEFAULT
            CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT
           )
PARTITION BY RANGE (P_DATE)
INTERVAL( NUMTOYMINTERVAL( 1, 'MONTH'))
SUBPARTITION BY LIST (ROLL_NO)
SUBPARTITION TEMPLATE
  (SUBPARTITION ROLL_1 VALUES (1),
   SUBPARTITION ROLL_2 VALUES (2),
   SUBPARTITION ROLL_3 VALUES (3),
   SUBPARTITION ROLL_4 VALUES (4),
   SUBPARTITION ROLL_5 VALUES (5)
    )
(  
  PARTITION VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(' 2019-08-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN'))
    NOLOGGING
    NOCOMPRESS 
    TABLESPACE DATA_PARTS
    PCTFREE    10
    INITRANS   1
    MAXTRANS   255
    STORAGE    (
                BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
                FLASH_CACHE      DEFAULT
                CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT
               )
    SUBPARTITIONS 5 STORE IN (DATA_PARTS,DATA_PARTS,DATA_PARTS,DATA_PARTS,DATA_PARTS),  
  PARTITION VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(' 2019-10-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN'))
    NOLOGGING
    NOCOMPRESS 
    TABLESPACE DATA_PARTS
    PCTFREE    10
    INITRANS   1
    MAXTRANS   255
    STORAGE    (
                BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
                FLASH_CACHE      DEFAULT
                CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT
               )
    SUBPARTITIONS 5 STORE IN (DATA_PARTS,DATA_PARTS,DATA_PARTS,DATA_PARTS,DATA_PARTS),  
  PARTITION VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(' 2019-11-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN'))
    NOLOGGING
    NOCOMPRESS 
    TABLESPACE DATA_PARTS
    PCTFREE    10
    INITRANS   1
    MAXTRANS   255
    STORAGE    (
                BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
                FLASH_CACHE      DEFAULT
                CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT
               )
               )
NOCACHE
NOPARALLEL
MONITORING;
```

When I run below sql I get the following error:

```
ALTER TABLE SCH.STU_DATA MOVE PARTITION SYS_P812325 TABLESPACE DATA_PARTS compress for all operations ;
```

Error Message:

```
ORA-14020: this physical attribute may not be specified for a table partition
```

Comment: Which version of oracle 11g you are using? for all operations has been changed to compress with OLTP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that your table is subpartitioned.

Not sure whether this will work - I don't have time to test it right now - but try this. Enable compress for the whole table then move the subpartitions.

1. `ALTER TABLE SCH.STU_DATA compress for all operations ;`
2. `ALTER TABLE SCH.STU_DATA MOVE SUBPARTITION whatever TABLESPACE DATA_PARTS;`

Probably a bit of a nause to write that all out by hand, but you can use ALL_TAB_SUBPARTITIONS to generate a script.